# Does codeigniter automatically sanitize email messages?

Tags: codeigniter, validation, email, sanitization

I read CI's documentation and about 50 posts, but I can't find a best practice for handling user inputs for email sending. For their example code from the manual:

```
$this->email->clear();

$this->email->to($address);
$this->email->from('your@example.com');
$this->email->subject('Here is your info '.$name);
$this->email->message('Hi '.$name.' Here is the info you requested.');
$this->email->send();
```

They have static text, which we know is safe. What if I used:

```
$this->email->to($this->input->post('message'));
```

Would I need to sanitize it somehow first to make sure that it first or does CI handle that in the email helper?

If I do need to, does this suffice with XSS protection turned on or do I need to do more than:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'required');
```

Does form validation with XSS protection enabled do the trick?

Comment: Considering that scripts don't work in emails, there's isn't really much you need to sanitize.  Email clients are built to weed out anything malicious on their end.

Comment: @SamDufel Good point. I can't actually think of anything I could enter into that form to cause a problem. The email address is validated and I think that may be all I need to do. I guess I don't want to make a bad assumption.

Comment: Well, simple using `$this->input->post('message', TRUE)` CodeIgniter returns the XSS cleaned value of the posted `message`.

Comment: @HashemQolami Thanks for the tip, but I have global XSS protection enabled.

Comment: @Citizen Enabling the global XSS protection cleans the `$_POST` variable completely. You could even use `$_POST` directly then.

Comment: @HashemQolami Thanks. I guess there's nothing else I need to sanitize before sending user input through an email...?

Comment: *Well,* I don't think so. Maybe censor some of words? :)

Comment: The only thing you might need to worry about is if you're including the user message inside an html email - in that case, you'll probably want to run htmlentities on the input to prevent errant HTML tags from being added.